# Implicit function theorem and consistency of a semi-explicit DAE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, multivariable-calculus

This may be a trivial question, but here goes:

Suppose a semi-explicit differential-algebraic equation (DAE) system is defined as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
&\dot x = f(x,z,\theta),\qquad x(0) = x_{0}\\
&g(x,z,\theta) = 0
\end{align}$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $z \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^{p}$ (a constant time-invariant vector). Suppose also that $g(\cdot)$ is at least once differentiable, and the Jacobian of $g(\cdot)$ with respect to $z$, which we call $g_{z}$ is nonsingular everywhere.

The vector $z$ is dependent, in that it is uniquely determined by $x$ and $\theta$. Its value is computed by solving the second implicit equation $g(\cdot)=0$.

Now, I want to perturb the value of $z$ by some constant quantity $d_{z} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
&\dot x = f(x,z+d_{z},\theta)\\
&g(x,z+d_{z},\theta) = 0
\end{align}$$

**Question**: Can I do so for any arbitrary value of $d_{z}$ without making the system of equations inconsistent?

**My partial reasoning**: I'm guessing I can, because the implicit function theorem tells me given a nonsingular Jacobian $g_{z}$, there is a neighborhood around some point ($\bar x$, $\bar z$, $\bar \theta$) which is the open-set denoted $X$, there exists a function $h$ such that:
$$
g(x,h(x,\theta),\theta) = g(\bar x,\bar z, \bar \theta), \qquad (x,\theta) \subset X
$$
Therefore if we take ($\bar x$, $\bar z$, $\bar \theta$) to be the solution point, we can write the explicit function:
$$
z = h(x,\theta), \qquad (x,\theta) \subset X
$$
Therefore, in the neighborhood defined by $X$, the system can be written:
$$
\begin{align}
&\dot x = f(x,h(x,\theta),\theta)\\
&z = h(x,\theta)
\end{align}$$
And I have a feeling that the perturbed system should be consistent, but I don't know how show this rigorously:
$$
\begin{align}
&\dot x = f(x,h(x,\theta) + d_{z},\theta)\\
&z = h(x,\theta) + d_{z}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I have this special case in mind: if I want to find the intersection of two or three spheres, it should be easy to make a perturbation that ensures the spheres are "far apart"...

Comment: @J.M. You're right; even for the simple case of the intersection of two circles, one can conceive a perturbation large enough as to give rise to two circles that do not intersect. I'm just wondering, is there a way to specify some conditions on $d_{z}$ or some such to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I'm doubtful that anything useful can be done, unless there's something special about both $f$ and $g$...

Comment: Suppose I change the question: instead of two systems of equations, I'd like to consider an index-1 semi-explicit DAE system (which is my real system of interest).